# Why does storing 7 floating-point numbers need 34 bytes?

Tags: linux, floating-point, operating-system

I have a file that stores 7 numbers in double. See below. But its size is only 34 bytes. Shouldn't it be 7*8 = 56 bytes instead?

```
$ cat data
17.2
18.1
16.5
18.3
12.6
0.75
0.25$ ls -l data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34 Apr 15 03:29 data
```

Comment: You're storing numbers as _text_, not in a floating point format.

Comment: @Brian How could I convert the file above to one of floating-point format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file contains text representations of the numbers (e.g. written out as digits with a decimal point and a newline separator) rather than as IEEE-754 floating point numbers. The byte count you’re seeing is for the number of characters used, not the number of bytes needed in IEEE-754 format.

Comment: That makes sense. 6 lines with 5 chars (including \n) and one line with 4 chars = 34 chars.